# Inequality on summation

Tags: combinatorics, inequality, summation

Let $\mathfrak{m},\mathfrak{n}\subset\mathbb{N}$ and we define $|\mathfrak{n}|=n_1+n_2+\ldots$, for $\mathfrak{n}=\{n_1,n_2,\ldots\}$. I am wondering is the following inequality true:
$$
\sum_{\mathfrak{m}\in\mathfrak{P}(\mathfrak{n})\setminus\{\mathfrak{n}\}}|\mathfrak{m}|! \leq |\mathfrak{n}|!.
$$
Here, $\mathfrak{P}(\mathfrak{n})$ denotes the power set of $\mathfrak{n}$. I have tried induction but it does not work for me. Can anyone clarify on this? Thank you!

Comment: In your question subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ are finite right?

Comment: You have tried induction on $|\mathfrak{n}|$ as in your definition or on the dimension of $\mathfrak{n}$? The second approach I think could be interesting

Comment: The subset is finite. I tried to do it by induction on the dimension of $\mathfrak{n}$.